# to do list won't show data from collection that i ran trough filter

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor, spacebars, meteor-helper

this is my code(i don't know where is the error for two days already.). And when I put .task and .Done helpers it won't show templates anymore. I know I have an error somewhere but I cannot pin point it for two days already. What I want is to pull tasks from database run them trough filter. Thank you in advance for your help.

```
<template name="Done">
    <li>
      <div>
        <span class="text">{{title}}</span>
      </div>
   </li>
</template>

<template name="task">
    <li>
    <button class="completed">Completed</button>
    <!--<li><input type="text" name="task" class="edit"></li>!-->
    <span class="text" onclick="true">{{title}}</span>
    <button class="saveItem">Save</button><button class="cancelItem">Cancel</button>
    <button class="editItem">Edit</button><button class="delete">Delete</button>
</li>
```

```
<div>
    <h1>To do list</h1>
        <ul>
            {{#each tasks}}
                {{>task}}
            {{/each}}
        </ul>
</div>

<div>
    <h1>Done list</h1>
        <ul>
            {{#each tasks}}
                {{>Done}}
            {{/each}}
        </ul>
</div>
```

.js file

```
 Meteor.subscribe("tasks");

 Template.body.helpers({
    tasks: function(){
      return Tasks.find();
  }});

    Template.Done.helpers({
taskDone: function () {
  return Tasks.find({}, {fields: {completed: "yes"}});
    }
  });

  Template.task.helpers({
    taskNotDone: function(){
  return Tasks.find({completed: "no"});
    }
  });

  Meteor.publish("tasks", function () {
   return Tasks.find({});
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, I strongly recommend to store the `completed` field as Boolean values instead of String values. Secondly, the helper functions `taskDone` and `taskNotDone` should belong to the `body` template. In addition, the `fields` modifier is usually used to limit certain fields for [publishing](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/meteor_publish) and not for querying documents.

For example, if you want to publish all tasks, minus the `completed` info, the publish function would look like this:

```
Meteor.publish("tasks", function () {
  return Tasks.find({}, {fields: {completed: 0}});
});
```

Instead, if you want to return only `Tasks` documents which have been completed, you would have the following query:

```
Tasks.find({completed: true});
```

---

This code may fix your problem:

```
<body>
  <div>
    <h1>To do list</h1>
    <ul>
      {{#each tasksToDo}} 
        {{>task}} 
      {{/each}}
    </ul>
  </div>

  <div>
    <h1>Done list</h1>
    <ul>
      {{#each taskDone}} 
        {{>done}} 
      {{/each}}
    </ul>
  </div>
</body>

<template name="done">
  <li>
    <div>
      <span class="text">{{title}}</span>
    </div>
  </li>
</template>

<template name="task">
  <li>
    <button class="completed">Completed</button>
    <span class="text" onclick="true">{{title}}</span>
    <button class="saveItem">Save</button>
    <button class="cancelItem">Cancel</button>
    <button class="editItem">Edit</button>
    <button class="delete">Delete</button>
  </li>
</template>
```

---

```
if (Meteor.isClient) {
  Template.body.helpers({
    tasksToDo: function() {
      return Tasks.find({
        completed: false
      });
    },
    taskDone: function() {
      return Tasks.find({
        completed: true
      });
    }
  });
}
```

Here's a [MeteorPad](http://meteorpad.com/pad/AHkbfDm2PpmXCpM9t/Tasks-Demo).